# How to test if a point inside area with lat/lon and radius using Java?

Tags: java, latitude-longitude, point, area

I've to write a method that has the following signature

```
public class Position {
double longitude;
double latitude;
}

boolean isInsideTheArea(Position center, double radius, Position point);
```

So if `point` is inside the `area` that has the `center` as its center and `radius` as its radius in **miles**, this should return `true`, `false` otherwise.

Comment: Actually, I'm not experienced in this field. But I see Haversine formula shall be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to compute the distance between `center` and `point`. If that distance is greater than `radius`, return `false`; otherwise return `true`.

Pseudocode:

```
def haversineDistance(a, b):
    # snip...
    return foo

def isInsideTheArea (center, radius, point):
    return haversineDistance(center, point) <= radius
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps  there are also some implementation examples
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula