# SQL query (in Crystal Reports) to return points in an area using longitude / latitude

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

I work for a small police department and we use crystal reports to build reports from our database.   Our department has four patrol districts (the city divided into four parts).  I am trying to build a query that will return incidents that occurred in one of the four districts.  Currently our database has all the locations in a table with each location having a longitude / latitude.

I was wondering if there was a way to build a query using longitude / latitude to query locations only in one of the districts (areas)? Unfortunately the districts are not perfect squares. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, depending on what the quadrants look like, assuming four sides, you could fit four linear equations of the form a+bx=c to the outer boundaries of the quadrant, for each latitude and longitude, determine if it falls withing those boundaries. You could also use a "brute force" technique with a huge lookup table If lat>x and lat<y and long>x and long<y. Sounds like an interesting project. Can you provide us more information? Shapes? dimensions?

Comment: What database are you using?  Databases vary alot in geospatial capabilities...

Comment: First question here is are the latitudes and longitudes dynamic in nature (or) static values that are stored in database. If those are static values and you know the values before building a query, I don't think it is difficult to write a query with latitudes and longitudes. Before that let me know how you get values for latitudes and longitudes

Comment: The latitude / longitude values are static and stored with each location.

Comment: Also the district area would be a multisided polygon.

Comment: In postgres, st_contains will work for you here (need PostGIS contribs installed).   MSSQL has an equivlent : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054149/sql-server-2008-spatial-find-a-point-in-polygon   and using oracle spatial here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601202/geo-fence-how-to-find-if-a-point-or-a-shape-is-inside-a-polygon-using-oracle-sp     I'm decently sure mysql has another option too.  Each database has a slightly different way of handling these spatial 'in polygon' requests.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541056/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303568/,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772690/